# AWS Application Load Balancer 502 Docker Swarm Spring Boot

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, docker-swarm, elastic-load-balancer

Hi I have an application load balancer that periodically throws 502 errors even though all the instances are healthy.

The Instances are docker swarm cluster to a set of spring boot applications.

This happens a lot specifically with the options request. The access logs are showing a 502 being thrown by the load balancer and no connection is being established with the instances.

Comment: Check out this answer, it might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50174356/321356