# ALB logs showing elb_status_code is 502

Tags: amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer, http-status-code-502

ALB is giving me 502 errors randomly during the playwright test. When I debugged and checked ALB logs in Athena and I found elb_status_code is `502`

Also access log entry says, the request_processing_time is 0.0, the target_processing_time is 0.005, and the response_processing_time is `-1`.

As per this AWS documentation:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-alb-troubleshoot-502-errors/

```
If the elb_status_code is "502" and the target_status_code is "-", then your load balancer is the source of the HTTP 502 errors
```

But I didn't understand a way to fix it. Can someone please help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - which caused due to the keep-alive timeouts (the server used shorter timeouts than the load balancer)
Take a look on that post:
[AWS Load Balancer 502](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071729/aws-load-balancer-502)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).